# In R what is an efficient way to fill a vector of unknown size?

Tags: arrays, r, dynamic

```
v <- c()
i <- 1
while (some_condition) {
    v[i] <- some_value
    i <- i + 1
}
```

So I am aware that each time v is modified a copy is made and v is moved. This is obviously very slow. This appears to be a trivia problem in other languages. What is the efficient way to do this in R?

Comment: If there's absolutely no way of knowing the size of the vector, (a) preallocating a vector with some padding or (b) preallocating a vector of some standard size and then `c()`'ing some of the time perhaps both sound less suboptimal?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no native method for populating a vector of unknown length without constantly rewriting it to memory. Maybe `data.table` has some tricks?

Lacking any sophisticated solutions, something as simple as preallocating an oversized vector, as 12b345b6b78 suggest, can save you a fair bit of time.

```
unk <- 1e5

f1 <- function(unk) {
    v <- c()
    for (i in 1:unk) {
        v[i] <- i
    }
    v
}

f2 <- function(unk) {
    v <- vector(length=unk*2)
    for (i in 1:unk) {
        v[i] <- i
    }
    v[1:i]
}

f10 <- function(unk) {
    v <- vector(length=unk*10)
    for (i in 1:unk) {
        v[i] <- i
    }
    v[1:i]
}

library(microbenchmark)
mb <- microbenchmark(f1(unk), f2(unk), f10(unk), times=50)
mb
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq       max neval cld
#   f1(unk) 27.177678 28.364024 32.65618 29.896673 36.18994  48.37088    50   c
#   f2(unk)  8.075867  9.025156 10.87335  9.271589 10.07932  35.29222    50 a  
#  f10(unk) 11.132773 13.071857 20.46808 15.059086 21.53610 187.00786    50  b
```